# re-captcha question

Tags: php, captcha

I have two pages apply.php (landing page) and mail.php which is the majority of the code for a online application project that ive been working on

I have a re-captcha account and I don't seem to understand how to apply the re-captcha code on two page senerio.

when i had all my code in one page i simply put the "mail();" code into the conditional of the captcha code.

but with i guess im unclear on how to use the captcha as post or don't post of the page data.

I can post the code if necessary but i just view the captcha as a fancy conditional statement Im just confused how to make

Comment: I believe recaptcha requires a form post to work. At least, if you want to use the code they provide for you. I'm having trouble understanding exactly what your questions is.

Answer (score 0):

Crash893 -- you need to let the page with the re-Captcha post.  But, the page it posts to doesn't automatically do its work.  First, do the tests in the tutorial that Zote mentioned.  Only do the work (sending the mail?) if is_valid is true.

If this doesn't help, could you post more details?